# How to write a script for count working time employee?

Tags: mysql

help me, please!

At the table - date, time, person, source. Updated with new values ​​when employee passing through the checkpoint, he can leave / came several times per day.

```
+---------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| date          | time     |person  |source       |
+---------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 01.08.2014    | 08:42:08 | Name1  | enter1      |
+---------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 01.08.2014    | 09:42:12 | Name1  | exit1       |
+---------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 01.08.2014    | 10:22:45 | Name1  | enter2      |
+---------------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 01.08.2014    | 18:09:11 | Name1  | exit2       |
+---------------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

I need to count for each employee the actual time he spent at work each day. Table will always be not editable. It is formed from a csv file. The script runs once.

I think need to do something like this:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, enterTime, exitTime)
```

for each employee for 1 day. But I have a very poor knowledge in sql.

Comment: there is no enter/exit time on your table, how to caculate the spent time then ?

Comment: Dates in SQL adhere to a specific format, and there's rarely a good reason for separating dates and times. Once you've fixed those issues, feel free to get to back to us.

Comment: @Strawberry you are an expert in downvoting

Comment: @Begueradj Er, yes there is!!!

Comment: @Begueradj Why do you say that?

Comment: try to use `TIME_TO_SEC` for converting time to second : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date/time formats should be stored in a datetime/timestamp column. It is possible to convert them, although ugly (there's probably a better way...):

```
> SELECT CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE('01.08.2014', '%m.%d.%Y'), ' ', '08:42:08');
2014-01-08 08:42:08
```

Now Suppose the times are unix timestamps. An employ arrives at `t0` and leaves at `t1`. The time he was at work is `(t1-t0)` seconds. Now suppose he he arrives at `t0`, leaves for a break at `t1`, returns at `t2`, and leaves for the day at `t3`. His total time at work is `(t1-t0) + (t3-t2) = (t1+t3)-(t0+t2)`. In general: his time at work for a given day is the sum of the arrival times subtracted from the sum of the departure times.

Using your times:

```
1389188528 enter1
1389192132 exit1
1389194565 enter2
1389222551 exit2
```

We see that total time at work is: `1389222551 + 1389192132 - (1389188528 + 1389194565) = 31590`, or about 8 hours and 47 minutes. Now what remains is converting to unix timestamps (`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`) and applying this reasoning via SQL. In the following example, I have added your data to a table named `work_log` and assumed that when `source` begins with `exit` or `enter`, we are respectively referring to a departure or arrival.

```
SELECT person, DATE(dt) AS day, 
    SUM(IF(`source` like 'enter%', -1, 1)*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt))/3600 AS hours
FROM  (SELECT CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m.%d.%Y'), ' ', `time`) AS `dt`,
    `person`,`source` FROM work_log) AS wl 
GROUP BY person,day;

+--------+------------+--------------+
| person | day        | hours        |
+--------+------------+--------------+
| Name1  | 2014-01-08 | 8.7750000000 |
+--------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are *probably* cleaner ways of doing that.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. But what if the employee came in one day and gone the next? It is necessary to subtract from 24:00

Comment: Changing the `GROUP BY` to `person` would yield the totals for _all time_, regardless of whether the enters/exists are on the same day. But the number of enters and exists still must be equal. You could add a `WHERE` to to look at all times between e.g. 0500 on day1 and 0200 on day2, but that's still not perfect. I'm not sure there is a good way of handling that in pure SQL.